# Annotate graph using data from Array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib graph that I have created using data from arrays. I want to annotate this graph at certain points. The x axis is populated with dates (14/06/12, 15/06/12) etc.. The y axis is price (6500, 6624) etc... I would like to annotate at point: for example (x,y) (14/06/12, 6500). This is my code so far:

```
Date = ["14/06/12", "15/06/12"]
Open = [6500, 6544]
High = [5434, 5234]
Low = [5342, 5325]
Close = [4523, 2342]
ohlc = []
i = 0
while i < 2:
    Prices = Date[i], Open[i], High[i], low[i], Close[i]
    ohlc.append(Prices)
    i += 1

candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.8, colorup='g', colordown='r')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.annotate('Here!', xy=(Date[1], Price[1]))
plt.show()
```

This is the current graph and I want the annotation on it where i put it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qM4D.jpg

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: What is currently happening now in your code that is not giving you the annotation you expect?

Comment: Also, can you give a sample of what exactly `Prices` is and what `ohlc` is exactly? I'm not a matplotlib person, but if someone wanted to assist here and wanted to test out your code, I would assume it would be helpful to give a small sample of the data.

Comment: Hey guys, updated the question, sorry!

Comment: Is it important to make use of `subplots` to perform this annotation? I'm looking at the documentation on annotation examples here: http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html#annotating-text

Comment: @TomPitts this is example is no where near runnable. At first, `Prices` was undefined, now `Date`, `Open`, `High`, etc are all undefined. What's `ohlc`? a list? where did `candlestick_ohlc` come from?

Comment: "*I want the annotation on it where i put it*" huh? is the img showing us what you want or what you have?

Comment: @PaulH Date, Open etc all take daily values like the FTSE would. Will edit question again, sorry! The annotation is what I would like to have, thanks!

Comment: @PaulH Updated it for you, hopefully that makes more sense!

Comment: what is FSTE? it's still not clear what's unsatisfactory about your call to `ax.annotate`?

Comment: @PaulH The FTSE100, its an index, stock market. ax.annotate does nothing, it doesn't plot any text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using the matplotlib.pyplot text command to add text to a plot at a specified location:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x))
plt.text(x=-4, y=0.5, s="Cosine", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

There are lots of additional formatting options available for text (alignment, font, etc.).  Full documentation is available here:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text